# algorithm for the sum of integer peer from n to n

Tags: algorithm, sum

i know how to do from 1 to n but from n1 to n2 i couldn't find an algorithm. exemple:n1=10 and n2=14 and the answer is  36 or n1=10 and n2=6 and the answer is  24.

Comment: How do you do it from 1 to n? Could you please show that, at least?

Comment: Do you simply want a non-inclusive addition? i.e. for n1 = 10 and n2 = 14 you just want to add 11 + 12 + 13?

Comment: If you know how to do from `1` to `n`, you already know how to implement the limited case of `n1` to `n2`. It's the case of `n1=1; n2=n`.

Comment: what is a "sum of integer peer"? what is a "integer peer"?

Comment: Could somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1 to n the formula is `sum =n(n+1)/2` , so from `n1` to `n2` you have to calculate sum of   `n1-1` terms snd sum of `n2` terms and then subtract.

```
sum_of_n1_to_n2 = n2(n2+1)/2  - (n1-1)((n1-1) +1)/2;
```

Comment: from 1 to n i use this (n/2)x((n/2)+1)

Comment: @AliAtas yeah both are same . your and mine. simplify it

Comment: ohhh i get it now thank you very much

Comment: and how can i do with an even number ? from n to n

Comment: @AliAtas I am not getting what  you want to say ?

Comment: i mean n1 = 10 and n2=14 the result will be 36 (10+12+14) the sum of even numbers between n1 and n2

Comment: @AliAtas use arithmetic progression formula.. `sum=n/2(2a+(n-1)d)` , where a = first term , n = number of terms and d= difference (in your case which is 2). so `sum= 3/2(2*10+(3-1)2) = 3/2(24) = 3*12= 36`

Comment: ahhh okey thank you very much and sorry for the trouble :D

Comment: @AliAtas welcome. see updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to sum from 1 to n, which is `n * (n+1) / 2`, that's already good.

Then just add the difference to n1.

```
int sumOfRange(int n1, int n2) {
  int n = n2 - n1;
  int triangle = n * (n + 1) / 2;
  int rectangle = n1 * n;
  return triangle + rectangle;
}
```